# In php result array generating not proper result?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image]

this is my table & my query is

```
$qrs=$select questionID,answer,count(answer) as answer_cnt 
  from `sg_finished_surveys` 
  WHERE  answer='$q' and questionID ='$questionID';
```

and

```
foreach($qrs as $qrow)
 {  
  ['<?=$qrow['answer']?>',<?=$qrow['answer_cnt']?> ],       
 }
```

result will get only last values

Comment: In foreach , what are you doing, explain it.

Comment: Are you getting the all result in $qrs. Just check it. print_r($qrs);

Comment: i want to  generate pie chart,so passing value !

Comment: NORMALIZE your database tables and you won't have to parse answers like that.